# Remote host can be connected to via SSH but cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: ssh, troubleshooting, digital-ocean

I am trying to find out why a remote host with which I can connect via SSH cannot connect to the internet.

When I try to ping said server, it will answer back with 1 ping and every subsequent packets are not received.

```
$ ping 138.68.93.123
PING 138.68.93.123 (138.68.93.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 138.68.93.123: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=7.44 ms
^C
--- 138.68.93.123 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 1 received, 88.8889% packet loss, time 8155ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.436/7.436/7.436/0.000 ms
```

Here's what's `traceroute 8.8.8.8` from the remote host look like

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

`route -n` output this :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         138.68.80.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.19.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.114.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
138.68.80.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

`iptables -l -V` output this :

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Here's what a traceroute to that remote host looks like

```
traceroute to 138.68.93.123 (138.68.93.123), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.88.1)  0.177 ms  0.214 ms  0.317 ms
 2  gw-tesag-eth.cyberlink.ch (62.12.154.121)  1.228 ms  1.398 ms  1.242 ms
 3  glbix-pe2.cyberlink.ch (195.144.164.2)  2.174 ms  2.262 ms  2.117 ms
 4  cybl-ch-zrh-pcr-001.cyberlink.ch (213.158.128.141)  2.193 ms  2.331 ms  2.224 ms
 5  zhtix1-br2.cyberlink.ch (213.158.128.140)  8.799 ms  8.880 ms  8.818 ms
 6  zhtix1-br2.cyberlink.ch (213.158.128.73)  9.270 ms  4.592 ms  1.620 ms
 7  31.217.132.145 (31.217.132.145)  9.236 ms  9.257 ms  9.285 ms
 8  fra1-edge1.digitalocean.com (80.81.193.141)  7.507 ms  7.796 ms  7.843 ms
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  138.68.93.123 (138.68.93.123)  8.299 ms  8.133 ms  7.950 ms
```

Connectivity interfaces

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ce:10:68:f7:c3:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 138.68.93.123/20 brd 138.68.95.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.19.0.65/16 brd 10.19.255.255 scope global eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cc10:68ff:fef7:c3bf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:29:c0:9f:a0:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.114.0.58/20 brd 10.114.15.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ac29:c0ff:fe9f:a076/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Is there any other kind of tool that I can use to diagnostic this issue?

Comment: Check your external firewall.

Comment: Does external mean that this firewall resides on another host? If that is the case, I suspected that this is probably the case but in my assignment I am only given access to one host.

Comment: What do you mean by "assignment"?

Comment: By assignment I meant schoolwork. So we have a bunch of constraints that might not apply to a real world situation